# Get nil when looking for file in subdirectory of main bundle

Tags: swift, file

I've copied a folder with `index.html` to the project.

[image]

When I try to get a path to the file inside a folder, I get `nil`.

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html", inDirectory: "games/game1")
```

I also tried to use "/games/game1" string. Doesn't work though.

But when I move `index.html` to the root of my project and use

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html")
```

I get a correct path.

So my question is how do I get the path of `index.html` inside a subfolder?

Comment: Did you make sure the whole directory structure is copied to your bundle? You can inspect your bundle and check that the files are really there?

Comment: @Sulthan I checked my project's folder and build phases: there are all files and folder, directory structure the same.

For example, 
/Users/karambirov/.../WebGamesTest/WebGamesTest/games/game1/index.html

Comment: I am not asking about the project folder, open the compiled .app bundle and check the files are there and in the correct folders.

Comment: @Sulthan I opened .app in finder with "Show Package Contents". Structure the same. In root there is a games folder.

Comment: Looking over our code, we have been always building the URL manually, e.g. `let url = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("games").appendingPathComponent("game1").appendingPathComponent("index.html")` However, I wonder whether directory "games/game1/" (with trailing slash) would work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is to use

```
Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "games/game1")
```

I don't know why, but it doesn't work if we get a path, then construct an URL from it.

**Note:** You must

1. Copy items if needed
2. Create folder references (not "Create groups")
3. Add to targets

Comment: Create folder references helps!

Comment: you see the only one is from me : )

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, adding to Eugene's answer,

**Swift 5:**

```
Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html", inDirectory: "games/game1")
```

Answer (score -2):

Please refer Apple Doc [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle)

> In summary
>   Apple uses bundles to represent apps, frameworks,
>   plug-ins, and many other specific types of content. Bundles organize
>   their contained resources into well-defined subdirectories, and bundle
>   structures vary depending on the platform and the type of the bundle.
>   By using a bundle object, you can access a bundle's resources without
>   knowing the structure of the bundle. The bundle object provides a
>   single interface for locating items, taking into account the bundle
>   structure, user preferences, available localizations, and other
>   relevant factors.
>
> Bundle structures vary depending on the target platform and the type
>   of bundle you are building. The Bundle class hides this underlying
>   structure in most (but not all) cases. Many of the methods you use to
>   load resources from a bundle automatically locate the appropriate
>   starting directory and look for resources in known places. You can
>   also use the methods and properties of this class to get the location
>   of known bundle directories and to retrieve resources specifically
>   from those directories.

You can add the index.html file anywhere in the project, but while fetching the use

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html")
```

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: @EugeneKarambirov       
You can add the index.html file anywhere in the project, but while fetching the use

let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html")

Comment: This is not true for resource folders.

Comment: However I have 2 index.html (in game1 and in game2).